# iterm2 - open new tab with same profile

Tags: iterm2

I'm switching from Terminal.app

Pretty straightforward, but I can't find it in the settings: I'd like that when I open a new tab (with cmd-t (or btw also with `oh-my-zsh`'s `osx` plugin's `tab` command)), the new tab uses the same profile than the current one (colors, fonts, whatnot).

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Shell` then `New Tab With Current Profile` (<kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>⇧</kbd>-<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>) does what it says on the tin.

Comment: This is great, but it's too bad there isn't a preference to make this the default (and have the special combo be for "open default profile")

Comment: You can bind any keystroke to any menu item with the "Select Menu Item..." action (it's the last one).

Answer (score 38):

I found some solution - although it should be simple global option.

You can go to keys definitions for each profile and there add mapping <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> > "open new tab with profile" and choose the same profile.

Comment: You can actually make this a global key preference, not just for each profile (don't have to set up each profile by itself, I mean)

Comment: For ITerm2 it is located in Keys > + > Action: *Select menu item* > New tab with current profiel

Comment: its called "New Tab with profile" hence why I missed it looking for new tab verbiage.

Comment: I think the new verbiage is 'Duplicate Tab`

Answer (score 6):

If you want this to happen as a default (the next terminal tab keep your directory):

1. Open iTerm2
2. Open Preferences
3. Open Profiles
4. Open General
5. Under working directory choose Reuse previous session's directory

Happy Trails!

Comment: This is a completely unrelated item to opening with the same profile. It's a nice tip, but it doesn't address the OP's request. What this does do is open the new window/tab in the same path as the one it's coming from. Note that the profile you're opening _into_ has to have this checked - the one you're coming from doesn't care. If you do, you'll get a new tab/window with whatever profile you're set to get (default if CMD+T or same profile if you use SHIFT+CMD+T or remapped CMD+T to do the same thing), plus the same working directory as your last window.

Comment: You did not answer the question of the thread, but you answered the question I had when I found this thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this globally using System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts

Select "App Shortcuts" in the sidebar and then add a new one. Select "iTerm2.app" in the Application dropdown, and then in the Menu Title section, type (exactly): **New Tab with Current Profile**

Then just press the shortcut you want in the "Keyboard Shortcut" section (I used <kbd>⌘T</kbd>) and it will override the current shortcut of <kbd>⌥⇧⌘T</kbd>.

Comment: This can also be done from within the Keys section if Term preferences

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking, I found a better solution for my use case. Similar to what *Eric Hanko* suggested, you can create a shortcut specifically for "**Duplicate Tab**" in *Iterm2* that is much more direct, and replicates the "duplicate tab" functionality that I was used to coming from *Terminal*.

1. Navigate to Systems Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts.
2. Select "App Shortcuts" in the sidebar.
3. Select "Iterm.app" from the Application dropdown.
4. Type an exact match for the menu item to shortcut, in this case `Duplicate Tab` as of the time of writing.
5. Add the shortcut. I used `CMD + D`.

**NOTE:** any shortcuts you create in System Preferences will override shortcuts already defined in Iterm2. This could lead to confusion later if you forget where your shortcuts are defined and get unexpected results using shortcuts in *Iterm2*.

Again, thanks to *Eric Hanko* for paving the way here.

Comment: This can now be done from within iTerm preferences. See other answers

Answer (score 1):

In iterm2, you can also map Cmd+T to the "New Tab with profile" action

1. Open Preferences > Profiles > Keys,
2. Select a profile
3. Add a new shortcut key for "New Tab with profile" action, set profile to match the currently selected profile, and set the shortcut to Cmd+T

You'll have to repeat this for each profile that you want to configure.

Answer (score 1):

A better way (IMHO) to handle this without system preferences:

1. In iTerm, to Preferences > Keys
2. Press + to Add a new key
3. Keyboard shortcut: command + t
4. Search for "Duplicate Tab" and select it

Done. Set once and forget.

This will always ensure the new tab uses the current profile.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a shortcut to the profile, then you can open a new tab with the profile.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l44CN.png)